# Pine Script - Build an exit condition that checks if I entered with a ceratin entry condition

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, algorithmic-trading

I am trying to code an exit condition that happen only if I entered with a certain entry condition.
Something like:
If ExitCondition1 then strategy.close //regular exit condition, no other conditions for it//
If ExitCondition2 and *I Entered with EntryCondition5* then strategy.close

Tried to set a var to 0 before the conditions, put a 1 value in it when I enter with the relevant entry conditions, add it  (if exitcondition2 and var == 1) to the exit condition, and reset it to 0 on any other occasion.

Also tried to identify the entry condition through the 'strategy.opentrades.entry_id' but didn't work, and I got in a mess with trying to exit two different entry ID's

this is the code I tried:

```
entryPrice = strategy.opentrades.entry_price(strategy.opentrades - 1)
RoundMacNorm = math.round(MacNorm * 100) / 100
RoundTrigger = math.round(Trigger * 100) / 100
RoundMacNormPrev = math.round(MacNorm[1] * 100) / 100
RoundTriggerPrev = math.round(Trigger[1] * 100) / 100
lastOrderID = strategy.opentrades.entry_id(strategy.opentrades - 1)
entryid = false

goLongCondition1 = (RoundMacNorm < -1.00) and (RoundTrigger < -1.00)
goLongCondition2 = (RoundMacNormPrev == -1.00) and (RoundMacNorm == -1.00)
goLongCondition3 = ((RoundTriggerPrev == 1.00) and (RoundTrigger > 1.00)
goLongCondition4 = ((RoundMacNormPrev < 0.1) and (RoundMacNorm == 1.00))

ExitLongCondition1 = (RoundMacNorm == 1.00) and (RoundTrigger == 1.00)
ExitLongCondition2 = (RoundMacNormPrev == 1.00) and (RoundMacNorm < 1.00)


goShortCondition1 = (RoundMacNorm == 1.00) and (RoundTrigger == 1.00) 
goShortCondition2 = (RoundMacNorm[1] == 1.00) and (RoundMacNorm < 1.00)


if inTradeWindow and (goLongCondition1 or goLongCondition2)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    entryid := false 
if inTradeWindow and (goLongCondition3 or goLongCondition4)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long) 
    entryid:= true
if inTradeWindow and goShortCondition1 and entryid == false
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short)
    entryid := false
if inTradeWindow and goShortCondition2 and entryid == true
    strategy.entry("short", strategy.short)
    entryid := false

if inTradeWindow and (ExitLongCondition1 or ExitLongCondition2)
    strategy.close("long", comment='Exit')
    entryid := false
```

Comment: ok, please paste the code you try.

Comment: I added it to the original question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option 1

```
var condition1Triggered = false

if inTradeWindow and (goLongCondition1 or goLongCondition2)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    condition1Triggered := true

...

if inTradeWindow and strategy.position_size != 0 and condition1Triggered
    strategy.close("long", comment='Exit 1')
    condition1Triggered := false
```

option 2

```
if inTradeWindow and (goLongCondition1 or goLongCondition2)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long, comment = "Entered With Condition 1")

...

if inTradeWindow and strategy.opentrades.entry_comment(strategy.opentrades -1) == "Entered With Condition 1"
    strategy.close("long", comment='Exit 1')
```